# Laravel Auth break with mobile browsers

Tags: laravel, authentication, session

I use Laravel 8.83 to build my site.

The website work fine for desktop browsers (edge, chrome and etc) however it break when i try on mobile browsers (safari and ios chrome).

So what happen is after the Auth::attempt() is called at login page, I try to log the Auth::user(), it seem to be fine but the issue arise when it is redirected to the next page where when I query the Auth::user(), it return null.

From one old dicussion without a solution i have read, it seems like it is due to session issue where the mobile browser get new sessions every call and I did verify it by printing out the session()->GetId().

```
Desktop browser
login session id: TWsa7xPcuc81DE7yleeeg1ezV1dSEWjijm2rviyf
subsequent page session id: TWsa7xPcuc81DE7yleeeg1ezV1dSEWjijm2rviyf

Mobile browser
login session id: fGtu4IJTEesA4BA7ov8NfiYIxWQL2MtmDsmb32DK
subsequent page session id: zTzXTteHb5cYG7oxrvfL5oNcy7fohu330wgf4i0P
```

Not sure whether there is a setting to make mobile browser behave like desktop browser?
Or any work around to make the authentication for mobile browsers work?

Update for closure for those people who faced this issue:

- The root cause is due to webkit 16.4 and 16.5.
- Since the chrome in the ios is also running the webkit instead of blink, it is also affected.
- Made the wrong observation which mention desktop browser is fine. Apparently I test it on safari in old mac and from what i heard in the link below, macOS with 'bad' webkit is also affected.
- Root cause due to safari has cookie successfully set but for unknown reason sent a null value to to the server which result  in my server assigning a new session id.
- Currently to enable users to login, I use remember function which seem not to be affected by the webkit bug.
- Lesson learnt: Pay attention to package or software versioning when t/s an issue.
- Link for the bug obtained with correct keywords: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=255524

Answer (score 0):

i think its a session management issue you are having, maybe the mobile browser is generating new sessions when a new request is hit but you should try using database or maybe you use redis or memcache sessions if you don't mind

But database is easier to configure try

Go to your `config/session.php` then edit your session config in your config or env

Default

```
 'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
```

Change it to

```
 'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),
```